Scifi movie about a guy having a boring job attending conferences
Trying to find a movie and watch it again, can't remember the title or actors.
It was about a guy having a boring job attending boring actuarial conferences (?), in one conference he wakes up, just to realize that they are being brainwashed. A few other things from his life also did not add up, I think he found out his wife is actually an actress that he paid to play his wife, but he had no recollection of why he did that nor was he sure that he wasn't just losing his mind.
These were what my fragmented mind remembers from that movie, some might be just from my mind and not the movie.
Any hints on possible movies that fit this description?

@richard : I know Truman show too well!

Sounds like a somewhat common plot. Can you supply us with some background details to narrow this down? Country\language, approximate year of release, when\where you watched it, genre (Was it more of an action film? Drama? Thriller? Sci-fi?) etc.?

@walt , in title i said scifi, couldnt think of it being thriller or drama, in scifi context it could be both or neither.

This sounds very much like Cypher:

Hoping for a more exciting life than the suburban drawl he currently inhabits, nerdy salary man Morgan Sullivan takes a job as an industrial spy at Digicorp, a global computer corporation. Digicorp assigns him the duty of flying to various conventions around America, recording the speeches that are made. But when Sullivan meets a mysterious woman he begins to realize that his job may not be what it seems, as he descends into a dark underworld of brainwashing and struggles to maintain his own identity.


yes, thank you. I thought it might have lucy liu in it but didnt think it was done in 2002! i thought it cou'dnt be more than 10 years old, so when i looked up lucy liu's imdb didnt scroll down enough.

@Arjang You should edit the question to include that fact (Lucy Liu is in the movie). This will make it easier if anyone else has a similar question in future.

@matt_black : That wont be fair to this answer, even i wasnt sure she was in it, TheBloodyPoet figured it out without Lucy Liu, otherwise even I would have figured it out and had no reason to post the question as it is.
